# related tag entries not working

Tags: tags

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="related_skus" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:tag:related_entries channel="men_clothing" tag="t shirt" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="6" paginate="bottom"}
            {exp:switchee variable="{channel_short_name}" parse="inward"}
                {case value="men_clothing"}
                    {stash:related}
                    <div class="each_ritems">
                        <div class="ritems_img">
                          {men_clothing_image limit="1"}<a class="image" href="{path='shop/product/{channel_short_name}/{url_title}}" title="View more"> <img src="{image:url:small}" alt=""></a>{/men_clothing_image}
                        </div>
                        <div class="each_rwrapper">
                          <div class="ritems_title">{exp:stash:get name="small_title"}</div>
                          <div class="ritems_price"> From: <div class="sus-rupee">{men_clothing_vendor:lowest column="mc_sales_price"}</div> To <div class="sus-rupee">{men_clothing_vendor:highest column="mc_sales_price"}</div></div>
                          <div class="ritems_details">{title}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/stash:related}
                {/case}
            {/exp:switchee} 
    {/exp:tag:related_entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="related_skus"}
      {related}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

i have tried this without Stash and passing channel name and nothing is working. need your expert advice

Answer (score 1):

[tag:related_entries](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/related_entries/) accepts an `entry_id` parameter, not a `tag` parameter. This is because it looks for entries which have many shared tags in common to the entry you pass to it. (Hence, entries which are "related.")

If you simply want to display a list of entries which belong to a specific tag, use [tag:entries](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/) instead.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the answer,, adding tag parameter is part of trial and error and without also i am not getting output from related entries.   there are entries with t shirts tag and that channel still no output.

Comment: Are you passing a valid `entry_id`?

Comment: I am having this related entries tag in single post page and outside channel entries tag. Do i need to pass entry id to work correctly.

Comment: When i move this code inside channel entries now i have oupt put , but all of them are same entries of entry id                                     {exp:stash:set_list name="related_skus" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:tag:related_entries channel="men_clothing" entry_id="{entry_id}" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="6" paginate="bottom"}
    {exp:switchee variable="{channel_short_name}" parse="inward"}
     {case value="men_clothing"}
      {stash:related}

Comment: Ah, right, it can't go inside of a `channel:entries` loop due to the variable names clashing. But if you put it outside of the `channel:entries` loop in the same template, Tag will infer the current `entry_id` from the URL and it should work. Otherwise, you'll need to embed your `tag:related-entries` loop and pass the `entry_id` via an embed parameter.

Comment: Yes Thanks Derek, moving to embed did the trick